# WPf, MEF Architecture design

Tags: wpf, mvvm, architecture, mef

i faced with some problems when designing architecture of my extensible programm.

I'm using MEF, MMVM Light Toolkit and AvalonDock.

The first problem is how display view for some `ViewModel` imported from another assembly using MEF.
To solve it, i'm exporting `ResourceDictionary` where i'm defining `DataTemplate`'s for views declared in this assembly.

`Dictionary`:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
  ...>
  <DataTemplate DataType="viewmodels:MyViewModel">
    <views:MyViewForViewModel/>
  </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And in constructor of `MainWindow` i'm importing all `ResourceDictionaries` and merging them with `MainWidow.ResourceDictionary`.
Is it good? It's also possible to specify 'scope' of `ResourceDictionary` to import it not to `MainWindow`, but to `Application` for example.

The second problem is `ICommands` and `CommandBindings`.
To populate `Menu` i'm exporting 'MenuItems' where i'm defining `ICommand`, `Text` and other stuff, but i don't know how to export `CommandBinding`, should i use `RelayCommand` for cases when i can't create `CommandBinding`?

The third problem is dialogs.
I found great article [Showing Dialogs When Using the MVVM Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36745/Showing-Dialogs-When-Using-the-MVVM-Pattern) and easily adapt it to MEF. But, for example, I have an `IDatabaseService` which don't have any View. 
The `Workspace`, main ViewModel, storing instance of `IDatabaseService` and creating menu item: `Connect to Database`. Using IDialogService Workspace opening some imported `IConnectToDbDialog` so `Workspace` don't know anything about it. When dialog closed, the `SqlConnectionString` should be passed to `IDatabaseService`.
So who must pass this `SqlConnectionString`, `IConnectToDbDialog` or `Workspace`.

The fourth problem is how to communicate with `IDatabaseService` correctly.
For example. In some View i have `Button`: 'Create Item In Database'. And how should i call `IDatabaseService` method `CreateItem(ElementType elementType)` when button clicked?
The problem, that there are a lot of buttons which create `Items` with different `ElementType` in database, so, i think, it's right to create some `ICommand` with parametr and create only one handler for this command which will invoke some method in `IDatabaseService`. But i don't know how.
The other solution is to send messages to `IDatabaseService` from `ViewModel` to create item.
which way better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to answer your questions.

1. It is good. You can merge either on XAML or code behind but I prefer XAML. You can put it on MainWindow.Xaml, which is in scope of main window or on App.Xaml, which is in application scope.
2. I did not export views before. In my opinion, if you put CommandBindings under Menu, it does not matter when it is exported then imported if the event handler in the scope of imported environment.
3. It depends. Theoretically you can put the service call in either owner's view model or dialog's view model. If your dialog have a create/submit button, for instance, and you expect the dialog keeps alive until submission is successful, then put it in dialog's view model so that you can keep it open when you handle exceptions. if you do not need the dialog keeps open, then you can put the logic in owner's view model after dialog is closed.
4. Command is better. Considering the view model gets IDatabaseService object from IoC container, You might have one ICommand property that accepts ElementType parameter or a paramerter can map to ElementType. In the execute method you call CreateItem passing the parameter directly or from mapper. On you XAML, you put type in the command binding. Does it make sense?

Hope it can help.

Comment: Thank you. 3 and 4 answers are clear, but i have some questions about 1 and 2, may be it's my fault.
1. I also prefer XAML, but in my task i have access only to main assembly source code and generic interfaces, i have no access to views or menu or other blocks source code, so i don't see any other solutions except mine.

Comment: 2. I don't know how to do this. I have access only to `IMenu` and `IMenuItem` interfaces and `MenuItem` class. In some assembly i am exporting `class Menu  : IMenu` and `DataTemplate` in `ResourceDictionary` to show menu in shell. And to add some `IMenuItem` i'm exporting `class MenuItem : IMenuItem` or calling method `AddMenuItem(IMenuItem)` in `IMenu` getted from IoC, so i can't define `CommandBindings` under `Menu`. I only can do it in code but it's problematically, but possible.

Comment: In shared assembly
    public class WorkspaceCommands
    {        
        public static RoutedUICommand ConnectToDB{ get { return connectToDB; } }
        static readonly RoutedUICommand connectToDB = new RoutedUICommand("Connect to Database", "ConnectToDatabase", typeof(WorkspaceCommands));
    }

and in `MainWindow` or in other place i have to create `CommandBinding` to handle it.

Comment: I did not see the command bindings have anything to do with your Menu here. Your RoutedCommand is defined on shared assembly and your command bindings are defined on XAML.

Comment: Can you explain please, i don't understand.